# PhoneGap release Application not installed

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, sign, phonegap-desktop-app

Iam using PhoneGap to create an Application

Now it  **works smoothly in debug mode** However **after I sign it** and convert it to release mode when i try to install it on phone it shows the problem

> Application not installed

My `config.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
  xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
  id        = "com.brilliantapp.seb7a2015"
  versionCode="5"
  version   = "1.0">
  <name>Seb7a</name>
  <description>
seb7a app helps u calculate zekr  </description>
  <author href="www.fb.com/DrOs96" email="Drusama2@gmail.com">
Osama Soliman
  </author>
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
  <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default" />
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
  <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
  <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
  <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
  <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
  <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
  <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
  <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
  <preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
  <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0x000000"/>
  <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false"/>
  <preference name="LoadingDialog" value=","/> 
  <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
  <gap:platform name="android" />
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/144.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/192.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxxhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/64.png" />
 </widget>
```

And My `key.keystore`

Please can Someone tell me **Where the problem ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't install the same version of your app twice on an Android phone ! That's simple !**

You have two options:

1. Delete the debug/current version installed
2. change the version of your app from `config.xml` file

Comment: how about i factory reset the android phone? still cant still same release version?

Answer (score 0):

Try signing it using the Jarsinger method. once you have run the release command place your keystore file in your ant-build folder, rename the unsigned app file to what you want then CD to ant-build and run: `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore seb7a1.keystore [yourAppName].apk [yourAppName]`

Answer (score 0):

First off - don't show your keystore like that.

This happens when you try to install the same package named app as a debug and a release.

Uninstall the debug version, reinstall the release version and it should be fine. This happened to me a few times before I realised what the problem was.